# Solving Socket.IO socket undefined on connection from Arduino?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, arduino

I'm trying to connect to socket.io from arduino. The service works from the browser, but if I try to connect from the arduino, when I look in the node log I created via console.log when a connection happens, the socket is undefined, but picks up the connection. Below is the protocol switching request, which returns a 404 not found, but socket.io does register a connection but doesn't define the socket.

```
client.print(F("GET /socket.io/1/websocket/"));
client.print(sid);
client.println(F(" HTTP/1.1"));
client.print(F("Host: "));
client.print(hostname);

client.fastrprint(F(":"));
char portBuffer[10];
itoa(port, portBuffer, 10);
client.fastrprint(portBuffer);

client.print(F("Sec-WebSocket-Key: ")); //dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
client.print(F("dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ=="));
client.println(F("Origin: ArduinoSocketIOClient"));
client.println(F("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat"));
client.println(F("Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13"));
client.println(F("Upgrade: websocket"));
client.println(F("Connection: Upgrade\r\n"));
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the output from it trying to reconnect over and over.]

I was thinking maybe I formed the request incorrectly, but I can't find any information for the socket.io protocol switching request so I don't know what to change. What I have done is loosely based on what I read in web socket protocol stand.